# How to make the bot multithreaded?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, openai-api, aiogram, gpt-3

I am writing a telegram bot based on OpenAI. There is a problem with multithreading. When one user asks the bot, another person can get the same information.
For example:
First user: Do you know Konstantin Polukhin?
Bot: Yes, and begins to describe it..

The second user: Do you respect him?
Bot: Yes, I know Konstantin Polukhin.

It is necessary to make sure that the data does not overlap and the bot can say something related to the request of another user.

I tried many methods that were suggested, but none helped.

Code:

````
from aiogram import Bot,types
import openai
import requests
from googletrans import Translator
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher


TOKEN = " "

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
openai.api_key = " "

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

my_list = [" ", " ", ""]

@dp.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    #print("\n" + my_list[0] + "\n" + my_list[1])
    
    translator = Translator()
    
    dest_language = "en"
    translated_text = translator.translate(message.text, dest=dest_language).text
    my_list[2] = "\n\nHuman: " + translated_text + "\n\nAI: "

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=f"{my_list[0] + my_list[1] + my_list[2]}",
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1024,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.0)

    dest_language_2 = "ru"
    translated_text1= translator.translate(text=response['choices'][0]['text'], dest=dest_language_2).text

    await message.answer(translated_text1)

    my_list[1] = "\n\nAI: " + response.choices[0].text
    my_list[0] = "\n\nHuman: " + translated_text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)```
````

Comment: `my_list` is global to your async method. Every concurrent call to `start()` will compete to fill it.

Comment: Is it possible to solve it somehow?

Comment: Probably. how about just moving `my_list = [" ", " ", ""]` inside your method to start.

Comment: This list saves the previous answer and your question. It is made so that the bot can maintain the essence of the conversation.

Comment: Then you need a session level container like an instance of a class per user/conversation so that `my_list` is conversation specific.

Comment: Can you please show me how this can be done?